# Assigning 2 dimension array to 1 dimension array for data loaded from server

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to assign a multi-dimension array to a single dimension array for my UITable View construction. I decide to use loop to save time as the data load is quite taxing for manual adding of array.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSString *responseString1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",responseString1);

    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    id sample = [parser objectWithString:responseString1];

    for (int i = 0; i < [sample count]; i++) {
        [tableData addObject:[[sample objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:1]];
        NSLog(@"%@",[sample objectAtIndex:i]);
        NSLog(@"%@",[tableData objectAtIndex:i]);
    }


    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Thing is now NSLog for 'sample' reflects data but NSLog for 'tableData' reflects NULL.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `tableData` is an empty `NSMutableArray`, just use

```
[tableData addObject:[[sample objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:0]];
```

If you actually want to change `tableData` instead of *building it*, use

```
[tableData replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[[sample objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Comment: Yes its an empty NSMutableArray. I'm building it. Now, there's no error but its not adding the data. NSLog of 'sample' showed the values but NSLog of 'tableData' displayed (NULL)

Comment: (NULL) means that you don't create tableData, you should use something like tableData=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[sample count]]

Comment: @aknew... Can you please give me the full syntax with respect to the code above? Thanx...

Comment: tableData=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[sample count]];
        
for (int i = 0; i < [sample count]; i++) {
        
        [tableData addObject:[[sample objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:1]];
        
        NSLog(@"%@",[sample objectAtIndex:i]);
        
        NSLog(@"%@",[tableData objectAtIndex:i]);
        
    }

Answer (score 0):

NSMutableArray isn't static c array like `id myArray[5];`, it's like c++ `veсtor<NSObject *>`, so you can't put elements in it with `[tableData objectAtIndex:i] = ...` , you should use its methods `[tableData addObject:...]` (puts element to the end of array) or `[tableData insertObject:... atIndex:i];`

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are trying to do is best translated to:

```
[tableData replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[[sample objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:0]];
```